# pandas "stacked" bar plot with values not added to give height

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am trying to display a bar plot in `pandas 0.18.1` where the values for the different columns are displayed on top of each other but not added. So this is I think a stacked bar chart without the **"stacking"** which adds all stack values.

So in the example below

```
import pandas
from pandas import DataFrame

so_example = DataFrame( [(15 , 0 , 0 , 4),(16,  0,  1,  4),(17 , 0 , 0 , 6)]).set_index(0)
so_example.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

This gives the `Dataframe`

```
>>> so_example
    1  2  3
0          
15  0  0  4
16  0  1  4
17  0  0  6
```

I get for the second point "16" a max height of `1 + 4 = 5` . Instead I want the max height to be 4 and the "1" shown in green like it is now.

[image: stacked bar plot]

How do I achieve this without subtracting artificially. Sorry I dont know what these "stacked" plots are called so all my searching failed to yield a simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

Please check out the following code, it is not a comprehensive solution, but basically achieve what you want.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

so_example = pd.DataFrame( [(15 , 0 , 0 , 4),(16,  0,  1,  4),(17 , 0 , 0 , 6)]).set_index(0)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
_max = so_example.values.max()+1
ax.set_ylim(0, _max)
so_example.ix[:,1].plot(kind='bar', alpha=0.8, ax=ax, color='r')
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.set_ylim(0, _max)
so_example.ix[:,2].plot(kind='bar', alpha=0.8, ax=ax2, color='b')
ax3 = ax.twinx()
ax3.set_ylim(0, _max)
so_example.ix[:,3].plot(kind='bar', alpha=0.8, ax=ax3, color='g')

fig.savefig('c:\haha.png')
fig.show()
```

[image]

---

**Here is my thinking:**

1. First of all, I tried the same thing as you did, tried finding some `plug and play` solutions, but it seems no
2. Then I tried to play with the values, but you clearly said you don't want to artificially play with the values. I personally think it really depends on how you define `artifical`, I mean do some data processing for the `Dataframe` before plotting it would not be that difficult.
3. Anyway, here we jump into the third solution, which is to play with the `axis`. Since basically, your request is to **make the bar plot in stacked way but with overlapping**. I mean usually the `stacked bar` means you stack everthing on top of each other without any overlapping, that is why it is called `stack`. But since you want to organize the bar in a way that the **smallest value is at the very front, the second smallest value is at the 2nd, so on so forth...**

So here, I use `twinx()` to create different axis layer for each data set, and to make things a bit easier for me, I didn't sort them but just use `alpha=0.8` to change the transparency only. and I didn't use functions for the whole thing. Anyway, I think this is one approach.